# Why does my rectangle move less quickly towards "down/right" than "up/left" with the delta time?

Tags: c, sdl

Here is my problem, I wanted to implement delta time in my game but noticed that when I go to the right and down the rectangle goes slower than up and to the left (so the += go slower than the -=).

I then asked on a forum by making a short example but I was told that it worked for them but not for me and I can't explain the reason, nor them either...

Here is my code as an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
 
#define WIN_W 640
#define WIN_H 480
 
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void) argc; (void) argv;
 
    /* Initialisation de SDL */
 
    if (SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s", SDL_GetError()); return 1; };
 
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow ("Test mouvement avec delta time", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIN_W, WIN_H, 0);
    if (!win) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s", SDL_GetError()); return 1; }
 
    SDL_Renderer* ren = SDL_CreateRenderer (win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
 
    SDL_Event event;
 
    /* Valeurs du programme */
 
    SDL_Rect rect = {(WIN_W-64)/2, (WIN_H-64)/2, 64, 64};
 
    uint32_t ticks_count = SDL_GetTicks();
    float delta_time;
 
    const uint8_t* keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    SDL_bool running = SDL_TRUE;
 
    /* Execution du programme */
 
    while (running)
    {
 
        /* Calcul du delta time */
 
        delta_time = (SDL_GetTicks() - ticks_count) / 1000.0f;
        ticks_count = SDL_GetTicks();
 
        /* Evenements SDL */
 
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            running = event.type != SDL_QUIT;
 
        SDL_PumpEvents();
 
        /* Déplacement du rectangle */
 
        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
            rect.y -= 200 * delta_time;

        else if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
            rect.y += 200 * delta_time;

        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT])
            rect.x -= 200 * delta_time;

        else if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT])
            rect.x += 200 * delta_time;
 
        /* Rendu du programme */
 
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(ren);
 
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(ren, &rect);
 
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
 
    }
 
    /* Closing the program */
 
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The rect coords are probably integral, so your assignment rounds towards zero.

Comment: Thanks ! it was indeed that, it's really stupid, so I replaced 'SDL_Rect' by 'SDL_FRect' and used 'SDL_RenderFillRectF()' to display it. Thanks again ^^